# TCP socket communication for image streaming and Texture2D error

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, tcp

I want to ask for some ideas about why this error occurs. 
First, let me show you [the symptom of my project](https://github.com/DoranLyong/TCP_tutorial/tree/master/D435_TCP_PyServer_UnityClient) <- .gif file is uploaded in this link.

I implemented this project with Python TCP server and Unity client. 
 
As you watch this .gif file, Unity displays the streaming depth image from the Python server. 
Although Unity seems to show the image stream in real-time, it also shows 'query mark' frequently.

I heard that this query mark is displayed whenever unity `Texture2D` is failed to receive data, but even I added a flag to check loading image is `true` or `false`, it always `true`. 
 
Furthermore, When you see the console of Unity, it also shows there are some lost-bytes comparing to the python console (black console is for the python).

I already tested this TCP server works well with python client(that code is also uploaded above link). 
 So, I assumed it is Unity's problem, but I don't know in detail and want to know how to fix this.

This is my Python TCP server:

```py
mport pyrealsense2 as d435
import socketserver
import socket
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
from queue import Queue
from _thread import *


# _Set queue 
enclosure_queue = Queue() 


# _Configures of depth and color streams 
pipeline = d435.pipeline()
config = d435.config()
config.enable_stream(d435.stream.depth, 640, 480, d435.format.z16, 30)
config.enable_stream(d435.stream.color, 640, 480, d435.format.bgr8, 30)



# _ D435 process 
def D435(queue):


    print("D435 processing", end="\n ")
    pipeline.start(config) # _Start streaming

    try:
        while True: 
            # _Wait for a coherent pair of frames: depth and color 
            frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()            
            depth_frame, color_frame = (frames.get_depth_frame(), frames.get_color_frame())

            if not (depth_frame and color_frame): 
                print("Missing frame...", end="\n")
                continue

            # _Convert <pyrealsense2 frame> to <ndarray>
            depth_image = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data()) # convert any array to <ndarray>
            color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())


            # _Apply colormap on depth image 
            #  (image must be converted to 8-bit per pixel first)



            depth_colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(cv2.convertScaleAbs(depth_image, alpha=0.05), cv2.COLORMAP_BONE)
            #depth_colormap  = cv2.bitwise_not(depth_colormap ) # reverse image

            #print("Depth map shape = ", depth_colormap.shape)   


            # _Encoding 
            target_frame = depth_colormap

            #print(target_frame.shape)


            encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),95]  # 0 ~ 100 quality 
            #encode_param = [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION,0] # 0 ~ 9 Compressiong rate 
            #encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_WEBP_QUALITY),95]  # 0 ~ 100 quality 



            result, imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', target_frame, encode_param)  # Encode numpy into '.jpg'
            data = np.array(imgencode)

            stringData = data.tostring()   # Convert numpy to string
            print("byte Length: ", len(stringData))
            queue.put(stringData)          # Put the encode in the queue stack


            # __ Image show             
            images = np.hstack((color_image, depth_colormap)) # stack both images horizontally             

            cv2.namedWindow('RealSense', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
            cv2.imshow('RealSense', images)
            cv2.waitKey(1)        



    finally: 
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        # _Stop streaming 
        pipeline.stop()







class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    queue  = enclosure_queue 
    stringData = str()

    def handle(self):

        # 'self.request' is the TCP socket connected to the client     
        print("A client connected by: ", self.client_address[0], ":", self.client_address[1] )


        while True:
            try:
                # _server <- client 
                self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()   # 1024 byte for header 

                if not self.data: 
                    print("The client disconnected by: ", self.client_address[0], ":", self.client_address[1] )     
                    break                

                # _Get data from Queue stack 
                MyTCPHandler.stringData = MyTCPHandler.queue.get()     

                # _server -> client 
                #print(str(len(MyTCPHandler.stringData)).ljust(16).encode())  # <str>.ljust(16) and encode <str> to <bytearray>
                self.request.sendall(str(len(MyTCPHandler.stringData)).ljust(16).encode())
                self.request.sendall(MyTCPHandler.stringData)  


                #self.request.sendall(len(MyTCPHandler.stringData).to_bytes(1024, byteorder= "big"))
                #self.request.sendall(MyTCPHandler.stringData)             


            except ConnectionResetError as e: 
                print("The client disconnected by: ", self.client_address[0], ":", self.client_address[1] )     
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # _Webcam process is loaded onto subthread
    start_new_thread(D435, (enclosure_queue,))  

    # _Server on
    HOST, PORT = socket.gethostname(), 8080 
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) as server:    

        print("****** Server started ****** ", end="\n \n")     

        try: 
            server.serve_forever()

        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            print("******  Server closed ****** ", end="\n \n" )
```

and Unity script:

`Client_unity.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



namespace imageStream_client
{ 

public class Client_unity : MonoBehaviour
{
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo;
    IPAddress ipAddress; // IPv4 
    TcpClient client_sock;
    const int PORT = 8080;


    NetworkStream stream;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("*****Unity frame started *****");

        ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];

        client_sock = new TcpClient(ipAddress.ToString(), PORT);
        Debug.Log("***** Client Connected to the server *****");

        stream = client_sock.GetStream();        

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {        
        //Debug.Log("**** Buffer streaming ****");

        // _Client -> Server 
        string message = "1";
        byte[] buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        stream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length); // spend the byte stream into the Stream 


        // _Client <- Server 
        byte[] recvBuf = new byte[client_sock.ReceiveBufferSize]; // total receiveBuffer size         
        int readBytes = stream.Read(recvBuf, 0, recvBuf.Length);


        //Debug.Log($"total receiveBuffer length: {recvBuf.Length}");
        Debug.Log($"Real-read byte length: {readBytes}");


        // _Set display image 
        byte[] image = new byte[readBytes];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(recvBuf, 0, image, 0, readBytes);
        Viewer.instance.SetImageToDisplay(image);

        //Viewer.instance.SetImageToDisplay();
    }


    }
}
```

`Viewer.cs`

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace imageStream_client
{
    public class Viewer : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public RawImage rawimage;
        public AspectRatioFitter fit;

        #region Data
        public static Viewer instance;
        private byte[] imageToDisplay;
        #endregion

        #region Get Set
        public void SetImageToDisplay(byte[] image)
        {
            DisplayImage(image);
            //instance.imageToDisplay = image;
        }
        #endregion

        #region API
        internal static void DisplayImage(byte[] image)
        {
            if (image == null)
                return;
            if (image.Length > 0)
            {
                //이미지 크기 생성 이후 streaming 되는 이미지 크기에 맞게 수정 해야함
                Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(640, 480);

                //byte형식의 데이터를 texture2D 형식으로 읽음
                bool load = texture.LoadImage(image);
                if (load)
                {
                    //이미지를 화면에 입힘(Canvas 아래 RawImage)
                    instance.rawimage.texture = texture as Texture;
                    //이미지 가로 세로 비율
                    instance.fit.aspectRatio = 640 / 480;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Awake()
        {
            instance = this;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            //DisplayImage(instance.imageToDisplay);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you moved your read function into update, which calles every frame in Unity, so you just cant catch to receive data.

The solution is:

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("*****Unity frame started *****");

    ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];

    client_sock = new TcpClient(ipAddress.ToString(), PORT);
    Debug.Log("***** Client Connected to the server *****");

    stream = client_sock.GetStream(); 
    StartReceiveFunction();
}

void StartReceiveFunction()
{
    // Can be Application.IsRunning or whatever bool you need to receive data
    while (true)
    {
         if(stream.CanRead && client_sock.ReceiveBufferSize > 0){
         bytes = new byte[client_sock.ReceiveBufferSize];
         stream.Read(bytes, 0, client_sock.ReceiveBufferSize);             
         Viewer.instance.SetImageToDisplay(image);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I also tried that way to remove the ```update()``` function and make ```while``` loop for receiving buffer, but the unity process paused in this form. That's why I added ```update()``` function...

Comment: and I have a question about ```update()``` function (I'm really a beginner in the Unity).  If I call another function at ```update()``` , is this another function called by subthread and does the main thread just proceed next ```update()``` frame?

Comment: update is executing on main thread every frame. So in your app you should download in another thread i guess, and then SetImage on main

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the problem and fixed it. 
 
The problem was the wrong implementation of the TCP server.

I changed the python server code like below:

```py
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    queue  = enclosure_queue 
    stringData = str()

    def handle(self):

        # 'self.request' is the TCP socket connected to the client     
        print("A client connected by: ", self.client_address[0], ":", self.client_address[1] )


        while True:
            try:
                # _server <- client 
                self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()   # 1024 byte for header 
                #print("Received from client: ", self.data)

                if not self.data: 
                    print("The client disconnected by: ", self.client_address[0], ":", self.client_address[1] )     
                    break                

                # _Get data from Queue stack 
                MyTCPHandler.stringData = MyTCPHandler.queue.get()     

                # _server -> client 
                #print(str(len(MyTCPHandler.stringData)).ljust(16).encode())  # <str>.ljust(16) and encode <str> to <bytearray>

                ###self.request.sendall(str(len(MyTCPHandler.stringData)).ljust(16).encode())  # <- Make this line ignored when you connect with C# client. 
                self.request.sendall(MyTCPHandler.stringData)  


                #self.request.sendall(len(MyTCPHandler.stringData).to_bytes(1024, byteorder= "big"))
                #self.request.sendall(MyTCPHandler.stringData)             


            except ConnectionResetError as e: 
                print("The client disconnected by: ", self.client_address[0], ":", self.client_address[1] )     
                break
```

I had tested this server code with a python TCP client. 
 
When the client connected to the server and spending-receiving data, it should know the size of the buffer to transmitted data by the server. 
So, `self.request.sendall(str(len(MyTCPHandler.stringData)).ljust(16).encode())`  is needed.

However, `TCPclient` class in C# is sort of different to python one. it doesn't need to receive the explicit buffer size of transmitted data from the server (maybe that was processed automatically inside). So, the above-mentioned python code line can be ignored.

I reuploaded the new version [here](https://github.com/DoranLyong/TCP_tutorial/tree/master/Python_Unity_imageStream(ver2)).